# Round values in tensor to values from a list

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to round the values in a 2D tensor to the nearest value from a given list, for example:

```py
# this is eager, but the solution must work with non eager tensors
data_to_round = tf.constant([[0.3, 0.4, 2.3], [1.4, 2.2 ,55.4]])
possible_rounding_results = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

# TODO: round `data_to_round` to nearest values from `possible_rounding_results`
# expected output: [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2 , 5]]
```

I was playing around with `tf.math.subtract`, `tf.math.abs` and `tf.argmin` in order to find the index of the minimal absolute difference between the lists using a for loop, but then I failed to combine them back to a tensor, and it didn't work at all with 2D arrays only 1D.
And I am not sure if its the correct way to approach this problem at all.

Due to my total lack of experience with TensorFlow, I have no idea how to tackle such issue sorry in advance for the shallow question I am just lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could try something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[0.3, 0.4, 2.5], [1.4, 2.2, 55.4]])
possible_rounding_results = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5,6], dtype=tf.float32)

tf.clip_by_value(tf.round(x), tf.reduce_min(possible_rounding_results), tf.reduce_max(possible_rounding_results))
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 1., 2.],
       [1., 2., 6.]], dtype=float32)>
```

The last value is 6 instead of 5 (as in your example) since 6 is closer to 55.4 than 5. If you meant to use `tf.constant([[0.3, 0.4, 2.5], [1.4, 2.2, 5.4]])`, you would get:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 1., 2.],
       [1., 2., 5.]], dtype=float32)>
```